dart instantiate subclass from super
I want a group of classes that are enum-like; we can't subclass enum, so a small class with one final int will do (const even better). I want the superclass to define some default behaviors, and let the subclasses override as needed. But that includes construction: I need a function or class generic on the super type to be able to create an instance of the subtype it's actually called on. For example (this doesn't work):
class A {
  final int x;
  A(this.x);
}

class B extends A {
  B(this.x);
}

T newOne<T extends A>(int z) {
  return T(z);                    // error
}

Dart doesn't allow that, so try a factory method:
class A {
  final int x;
  A(this.x);
  factory newOne(int z) { return A(z); }
}

class B extends A {
  B(this.x);
  factory newOne(int z) { return B(z); }
}

T new one<T extends A>(int z) {
  return T.newOne(z);           // also doesn't work
}

Then Github copilot suggests I use a factory method variable:
typedef AFactory<T extends A> = T Function(int x);

class A {
  final int x;
  AFactory factory;
  A(this.x): factory = A.newOne;
  factory newOne(int z) { A(z); }
}

class B {
  B(this.x): factory = B.newOne;     // error
  factory newOne(int z) { B(z); }
}

That tells me that "factory" is not a class member!
I've even tried the class A<T extends A> thing that has worked
in the past to get ordinary (non-factory) methods to return a subtype
from methods defined in the super. But Dart won't let me do anything
with constructors or factories. This is doable in other languages.
Is there some magic technique or undocumented little corner of the
language I'm missing?

Nothing you are missing. You cannot invoke static members or constructors through a type variable in Dart. There is no syntax that makes it work.

Yeah, that makes generics much less useful. I couldn't find a good workaround either, so for now I'm just using the base class for everything.

I think I've found an ugly workaround:
typedef VFactory<V> V Function(int x);
class Base<V extends A> {
  VFactory get vf {
    return (int x) => A(x) as V;
  }
}

Then I can call vf(x) in my superclass, and in the subclass it will call the overridden getter with the subclass lambda, It shouldn't be this hard. Generics work fine in other languages.

That "works", but only if you have an instance of the class you want to create an instance of. So to create an instance you must already have an instance. It's turtles all the way down.

I'm creating the instances from a different object that's generic on the superclass, and it correctly constructs the subclass instance.
